# How to clear ad hoc queries from plan cache?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, plan-cache

As the title implies, I'm going to remove just ad hoc queries (not prepared queries) from plan cache in sql server 2014/2016 because it occupies more than 50% percent of my main memory. Do you have any suggestion?

Many Thanks.

Comment: You can find some examples here :  https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/eight-different-ways-to-clear-the-sql-server-plan-cache/

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm looking forward a way to clear just ad hoc queries from cache plan not all the things that are located there...@SabinBio

Comment: Looking at the link, at the Example 8 - here you can remove a particular plan , base on a plan handle.

Comment: Consider turning on the [`'optimize for ad hoc workloads'` server configuration option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/optimize-for-ad-hoc-workloads-server-configuration-option) so that plans for ad-hoc queries are cached only executed multiple times.

Comment: What do you expect to gain from doing this? Those ad hoc queries will be removed from the plan cache if they're old enough and room in the cache is required for a newer plan. @DanGuzman's suggestion of `optimize for ad hoc workloads` is the correct approach to use; only minimal space in the cache will be used for a single-use ad hoc query plan.

Comment: `a way to clear just ad hoc queries from cache plan` - we get it, but WHY? The setting Dan suggests is a much more effective and automatic way to limit the effect of ad hoc plans on the plan cache than clearing it manually whenever the thought occurs to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @plan_handle varbinary(64)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT plan_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
WHERE objtype = 'Adhoc' -- and usecounts = 1 -- optional: just delete the ones that are used only once

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @plan_handle  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (@plan_handle);  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @plan_handle 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 7):

So you just want to clear the Ad-hoc query plans and still dont want to clear the whole procedure cache. What you are asking is there in [Clearing Your Ad-hoc SQL Plans While Keeping Your SP Plans Intact](https://web.archive.org/web/20190208140938/https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/maciej/archive/2008/09/21/clearing-your-ad-hoc-sql-plans-while-keeping-your-sp-plans-intact.aspx)

The blog asks you to run

`DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('SQL Plans')`

As per the blog

> The procedure cache actually consists of 4 distinct cache stores that hold different types of plans. Those cache stores are:
>
> - CACHESTORE_OBJCP - these are "Object Plans" - stored procedures, functions and triggers. Generally, the good stuff.
> - CACHESTORE_SQLCP - these are "SQL Plans" - ad-hoc SQL statements (including parameterized ones) and prepared statements. This is the
>   stuff that we are after.
> - CACHESTORE_PHDR - so-called "Bound Trees" for views, constraints and defaults. Irrelevant for the problem discussed.
> - CACHESTORE_XPROC - not really execution plans but rather pointers to the entry points of your extended SPs.

So you can see *selectively* clearing the SQLCP would remove prepared and ad-hoc plans. I tested this on my system.

Ran query

```
select objtype, 
count(*) as number_of_plans, 
sum(cast(size_in_bytes as bigint))/1024/1024 as size_in_MBs,
avg(usecounts) as avg_use_count
from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
--where objtype='adhoc'
group by objtype
```

And the output was

[image]

You can see the the picture has `1264` ad-hoc plans and `69` prepared statements.

Now I selectively clear the SQLCP using `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('SQL Plans')` and rerun the query again which gave me below output

[image]

Now you can see the ad-hoc and prepared plans are 2 and 6 respectively. While other are NOT affected.

Comment: The original question was to "remove just ad hoc queries (not prepared queries) from plan cache ".  Your answer removes the prepared plans as well.  This answer should not have been marked as correct.

Comment: Marking answer is with OP. I have mentioned in my answer *so you can see selectively clearing the SQLCP would remove prepared and ad-hoc plans* which was OK with OP so he marked it. If you have way to *just* remove ad-hoc queries feel free to add